# Node is not recognized

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, atom-editor

so I use atom, I have installed script and when i try to execute my javascript I get this error:

```
[Command: cmd '/c C:\Users\Stelios\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\.bin\babel --filename C:\Users\Stelios\.atom\packages\script\node_modules\.bin\babel < C:\Users\Stelios\AppData\Local\Temp\atom_script_tempfiles\08a4ca80-fe01-11e8-bc01-85e8d2a83c37.js| node']
'node"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
[Finished in 0.075s]
```

Any thoughts how to fix this? I created a folder called node.js in program files set a path and it did not work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node is not recognized means either node is not installed or path is not set.

So install Node JS on your Windows machine from https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Check out this guide on how to install Node properly while setting path - https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/install-node-js-npm-windows

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, NodeJS does not work propertly in all directories. After properly installing it (https://nodejs.org/en/download). Just write this on your terminal (CMD) and it should work just fine:

```
SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```